# Accessing intermediate tensor of a TF2 keras tensor graph

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Is it possible to access the intermediate `Tensor` object in a TensorFlow 2 graph? By this, take the following short example:

```
x1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,name="l1")(x1)
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,name="l2")(x2)
x4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,name="l3)(x3)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x1,outputs=x4)

other_x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
model_out = model(other_x)
```

`model_out` here is a `Tensor` object (it has shape: [None,1]).
I would like to access the intermediate tensor that would be e.g. after the second dense layer is evaluated (the output of the "l2" layer). I believe this tensor is buried somewhere in the `model_out.graph`, but I'm not sure of the best way to extract it? I don't want to build a separate model, since in my actual case there are some stochastic (random) layers, so I do want to get at the intermediate tensor in the graph.

Thanks!